# How to create Single feature vector by concatenating RGB vectors in python

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, numpy

I am trying to plot RGB histogram for images. I am able to do it for single image for each channel using cv2 library. Here is the code i've been using:

```
image =  cv2.imread("path")
image = cv2.resize(image,(width, height)) 
chans = cv2.split(image)
colors = ("b", "g", "r")
plt.figure()
plt.title("'Flattened' Color Histogram")
plt.xlabel("Bins")
plt.ylabel("# of Pixels")
features = []

    # loop over the image channels
for (chan, color) in zip(chans, colors):
    # create a histogram for the current channel and
    # concatenate the resulting histograms for each
    # channel
    hist = cv2.calcHist([chan], [0], None, [256], [0, 256])
    features.extend(hist)

    # plot the histogram
    plt.plot(hist, color = color)
    plt.xlim([0, 256])
```

What are some efficient ways to concat RGB vector for multiple image so that I can have combined RGB Histogram for complete set of image.

Edit:
Is vectorizing each image and then using `np.hstack()` a correct way to concatenate image vector and Plot RGB histogram?

Comment: Your example works well for one image. The variable `hist` (np.shape=(256L,1L))   can be transposed into a 1D numpy array like so `hist1= np.transpose(hist)[0]` and then added to an (outside loop) accumulator by simply numpy array addition.   `acc= np.zeros((3,256))  .... acc[i,:]+=hist1` where i is an additional numeric iterator in your loop.

Comment: Yes, got it! Basically they are just fixed size vectors and we just need to sum up all the image vectors.